# C# Winforms Represent a Single Object as a Table

Tags: c#, winforms, class, display, tabular

C# Winforms.  I have a class.  It has some public member variables.  I want to display the values of the different members of the class in a table of two columns. First column is the member name, second is the value.

Note: I don't have a collection of these, just one, So I don't want a DataGridView.

Ideally, I would just like a control that I can bind my class to, then change the displayed text of first column to something readable for each member. Additionally, the member's values will change during program execution, and the table should update accordingly.

I don't see a convenient control for this - or am I missing something?  Seems pretty basic.

Comment: [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) or [VisualHint SmartPropertyGrid](http://visualhint.com/propertygrid)

Comment: Not sure why this would get downvoted.  Adding a comment would be nice way to explain.

Comment: I saw PropertyGrid.  It's very ugly.  Can I strip all of that extra stuff away?

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @C-PoundGuru I don't get it.  I have described a problem.  I'm not looking for a recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

Your end result will be a table, where every row in the table has two cells: Member name and Value.

The value can be any type of object, the displayed value must be a string. if you want to display some values in other types then string, for instance pictures, colors, hieroglyphs, whatever, you need some conversion from value to DisplayValue.

```
class DisplayValue
{
    public string Description{get; set;}
    public object Value {get; set;}
    public string DisplayedValue {get {return this.Value.ToString();} }
}
```

So you've got one object of some type, and you have a sequence of properties of this object you want to display.:

```
MyType myObject = ...
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertiesToDisplay = typeof<MyType>.GetProperties()
    .Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.CanRead);

IEnumerable<DisplayValue> displayValues = propertiesToDisplay
    .Select(property => new DisplayValue()
    {
        Description = property.Name,
        Value = property.GetValue(myObject),
    });
```

If you don't want to display all properties, but only the properies with certain names:

```
IEnumerable<string> propertyNames = new string[]
{
    "Id", "FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName",
    "Street", "City", "PostCode",
};
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertiesToDisplay = propertyNames
    .Select(propertyName => typeof<Student>.GetProperty(propertyName));
```

To Display them in a DataGridView, the easiest method would be to use the designer:

- Add a BindingSource
- BindingSource.DataSource = DisplayValue
- Add a DataGridView
- DataGridView.BindingSource = bindingSource1
- Add columns: one for Description and one for DisplayedValue

Whenever you are ready to display the values, for instance when form loading:

```
MyType objectToDisplay = ...
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertiesToDisplay = ...
IEnumerable<DisplayValues> valuesToDisplay = propertiesToDisplay
    .Select(property => new DisplayValue()
    {
        Description = property.Name,
        Value = property.GetValue(myObject),
    });

this.BindingSource1.DataSource = new BindingList<DisplayValue>(valuesToDisplay.ToList());
```

That's all there is to it. Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: Thanks!  I know there should be a way to glue it together manually - looks like the property approach does that.  In the end, I just made a simple User Control that populates a table-like display.  This method allows for the binding.  My hope was that winforms would provide a control that automatically binds a class in a similar manner as this, without having to add in all the plumbing to the class itself.  I use the class to communicate between remote process via http and json serialization, so I really did not want to have to add this kind of weight to it.  But nicely done.